# How to Completely Remove Footer in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

As per [How to Remove Footers of LaTeX Beamer Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435837/how-to-remove-footers-of-latex-beamer-templates), I can replace default footer with page numbers as follows:

```
%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

%gets rid of navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

But this is still unsatisfactory to me. I would like to completely remove the footer in some cases.

For instance, when I use the `draft` option, the footer will be opaque and completely covered. If some bullet points end up in that region, even partly, they can't be visible then.

So how can I completely remove the footer in Beamer presentations?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @samcarter I imagine this is an automated comment. Since the only answer is my own, I don't feel the need to mark it as accepted. Either way, on SE "answered" questions seems to be defined (loosely) by having at least one answer with an upvote, which is indeed the case here. Not sure anything else is needed.

Comment: It was indeed a building block. But you can also accept your own answer if it solved your problem. This shows other users that the problem is solved and there is no need to dig into the problem.

Answer (score 44):

As it turns out, to get a completely blank bottom of a Beamer document you need to do this:

```
%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

%gets rid of bottom navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%gets rid of footer
%will override 'frame number' instruction above
%comment out to revert to previous/default definitions
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
```

Now the Beamer footer is squeaky-blank, and when compiling using the `draft` option absolutely nothing encumbers the bottom part of the document. When removing the `draft` option for final compilation, you can comment out this last line to revert to previous definitions or to defaults.

Comment: You do not need the first line, if you have set the whole ``footline`` to ``{}``. And for the second one there is a command: ``\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty`` disables the navigation symbols.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar fashion, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]` to replace the footer line in all the slides with a simple slide count. If you want to keep the footer, but remove the header instead, simply use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}`. These have to do with the outer theme **infoline** in the beamer. If you don't use or comment the `\useoutertheme{infolines}` in the corresponding .sty file, both are removed.

[image: No header in the slides, but footer is present]

Code for this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{AbhiGreen} % this is my custom theme, you can use yours
\setbeamertemplate{headline} % this is the line/code you need to add to get rid of header

}

\title[short title]{title}
\author{Abhinav Sinha}
\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology, Bombay (Mumbai), India \\
\medskip
\texttt{sinha.abhinav@iitb.ac.in}}
\date{\today}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{IITBombayLogo.png}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give a little more details and include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show that this works?

Comment: Sure. From landroni's answer, replace footline with headline and you get something like the one in the edited answer.